# Mask URL to make the host URL invisible and use the main domain as WordPress permalinks?

Tags: domains, wordpress, masking

I use one hosting for all of my domains (approx. 15 of them) and I have a WordPress installed for one of them.

Let's say, my main hosting domain is: `hosting.example.net`

And I have installed WordPress to the subfolder: `hosting.example.net/wp`

Then, I've forwarded my domain `www.example.com` to `hosting.example.net/wp` WITH masking. So, I have `www.example.com` for all pages.

Now, here's the problematic part: Masking is not a SEO-friendly practice, because I cannot take advantage of SEO-optimized permalinks (e.g. `www.example.com/books`). But at the same time I do not want my hosting domain `hosting.example.net` to be visible (e.g. `hosting.example.net/wp/books`).

Is there a workaround for this to get permalinks like `www.example.com/books`?

Comment: Instead of thinking in terms of "domains", think in terms of the "filesystem".  Where do `abhosting.com` and `maindomain.com` resolve to in terms of the "filesystem"?

Comment: Does your host support add on domains?

Comment: Hello @docroot - thank you for your answer. Can you please clarify what you meant by 'Where do abhosting.com and maindomain.com resolve to in terms of the "filesystem"'? Thanks :)

Comment: Hello @StephenOstermiller - thank you very much for your answer. Yes, my hosting allows me to host up tp 25 domains. That's actually where the problem stems from - I want to host my websites on the same hosting but I do not want my hosting URL to be visible, but want SEO-optimized permalinks with my main domain.

Comment: So can you put your main domain in as add-on domain?   Then your hosting provider will use it, rather than their own.

Comment: Pretty much as Stephen suggests (or an Alias/Parked domain), then the two domains point to the same filesystem (not different accounts) and you may not have to do anything more. Or maybe you will need a simple internal rewrite to the required subdirectory. I would add, however, that hosting many "different" websites off the same "account" is not recommended.

Comment: Hello @StephenOstermiller and docroot - I am already doing so. I've set my domain as a add on domain referring to the folder of the hosting where the Wordpress is installed. However, all URLs belong to the hosting domain, e.g. www.abhosting.com/books, not www.maindomain.com/books - that's the problem I've been talking about.

Comment: In that case, it may just be a matter of setting the domain name in the WordPress settings

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I've tried it before, I get the website logo and menu but 404 error for the content. Any guesses what the problem could be?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Here's the screenshot: https://hizliresim.com/Dd2v8z

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'workaround' - you need to proxypass from a server registered to example.com. This means serving URLs as example.com/books but have your server source the content from hosting.example.net.

This involves configuring your server (Apache/Nginx/IIS). An example for Apache would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/whatever"
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPass  http://hosting.example.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It sounds like they are trying to use options available at the domain registrar without buying additional hosting.  ProxyPass isn't going to be available to them there.

Comment: Exactly. I want to use only one hosting to host all of my websites.